# How do I get a stack backtrace from a tracepoint? (GDB)

Tags: debugging, gdb

According to [these docs](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Tracepoint-Restrictions.html) it isn't possible to get a complete stack backtrace from a tracepoint, but it is possible to get a partial trace by recording a section of the stack.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've approximated the behaviour I wanted using commands on a breakpoint to print a backtrace then auto-continue:

```
> break functionName
> commands
> bt
> continue
> end
```

Comment: "break functionName" is a break point and not tracepoint. Is there any way to achieve the same with tracepoints ?

Comment: @AUZKamath I couldn't find a way to do it. Auto-continue breakpoints run pretty quickly though (and you can add 'silent' as the first command to suppress printing that the breakpoint was hit).

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I just found something related to this [in the gdb documentation 13.1.10 tracepoint restrictions](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Tracepoint-Restrictions.html) which says that it is not possible to collect the result of the backtrace command in a tracepoint, but it's possible to collect the stack by reading something like `*(unsigned char *)$esp@300`. You'll probably need to adapt a little bit: you may need to read more bytes, and the stack pointer may have a different name (rsp for x86-64)
Otherwise:

```
>collect *(unsigned char *)$esp@300
'esp' is a pseudo-register; GDB cannot yet trace its contents.
```